# Open Gromov-Witten invariants via lozalization with $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ (not $S^1$) action

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory, gromov-witten-theory, calabi-yau, localization

Amplitudes of open A-model on a Calabi-Yau 3-fold $X$ with branes are given by the open Gromov-Witten invariants of $X$. It is known how to compute them if there is a toric action on a manifold, which preserves all the branes and the image of the curve (see [Katz, Liu, Enumerative Geometry of Stable Maps with Lagrangian Boundary Conditions and Multiple Covers of the Disc](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0103074)
 and [Graber, Zaslow, Open-String Gromov-Witten Invariants: Calculations and a Mirror "Theorem"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109075)
 for examples). It is done via equivariant localization on the fixed points of the toric action.

All the references I read, consider the toric action with integer weights (thus $S^1$), while the brane configuration I have is preserved only by certain $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ action, which rotates some of the coordinates by $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} b}$, while the others by $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i/b}}$, for irrational $b$. If I try to follow the usual procedure used for the cases of $S^1$ action, I get the result which contradicts my physical expectations. I suspect that the reason is that this procedure must be modified appropriately in order to deal with irrational weights.

Could anybody recommend any reference in which such a problem is discussed?

Comment: Unless $b^2$ is rational, the set $(e^{ ibn}, e^{-in/b})$ is dense in $S^1 \times S^1$. So if your manifold is closed in the coordinates you're using it should extend to a $S^1 \times S^1$ action.

Comment: The manifold is not closed. It is an $S^2 \times S^3$ conifold, which is also an $\cal{O}(-1) \oplus \cal{O}(-1)$ bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$, so the orbits of the $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ action are infinite helices, and just two closed 1-cycles.